# while( var row = fn() );

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any equivalent metod to make like an php mysql_fetch_array while loop in js?

in php you can do:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "my name is " . $row['name'] . " and i'm " . $row['age'] . " yeas old";
}
?>
```

i have this object/array:

```
function fetch_array(arr) {
    // My magic fn that dose not work well, b/c it change the orginal refence
    return arr.shift();
}
var result = [{
    name: "Bob",
    age: 12
}, {
    name: "Jim",
    age: 18
}]

// And want to do:


while (row = fetch_array(result)) {
     alert("my name is " + row["name"] + " And I'm " + row['age'] + " years old");
 }

// returns zero :(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ dont want that
console.log(result.length);
```

Comment: I think they want the array to remain unchanged.

Comment: Remember to declare the variable `row`, otherwise it'll be an implicit global.

Answer (score 4):

I changed your `fetch_array` function in this way

```
function fetch_array(arr) {
   var i = fetch_array.i || 0;
   fetch_array.i = ("undefined" === typeof arr[i])? 0 : i + 1;
   return arr[i]; 
}
```

and this leave untouched your array. The idea is to attach and increment an index property to the the function itself

**Edit**: I had to reset the index when the end of array is reached, otherwise you would not be able to loop more than once on the same (or different) «resultset», e.g.

```
while(row = fetch_array(result)){
    alert("my name is " + row["name"] + " And I'm " + row['age'] + " yo");
}

while(row = fetch_array(result)){
   alert("here again the name " + row["name"] + " and age: " + row['age']);
}

console.log(result.length); // returns 2;
```

as aside note, the condition to reset the index could be also done with

```
fetch_array.i = (i === arr.length)? 0 : i + 1;
```

Comment: could you formulate an example of what are you trying to accomplish? Post a fiddle

Comment: but also your original example cannot work with nested `while()`.. I think you cannot achieve this behaviour without using another syntax or totally modifing the code (e.g using iterators - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) but this is not what you want I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.shift` removes the first element of the array, so when you're done looping through it like that, it's empty.

If all you want to do is to go through it and use the data, try this:

```
var row;
for (var i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++) {
    row = result[i];
    alert("my name is " + row["name"] + " And I'm " + row['age'] + " years old");
}

// returns 2
console.log(result.length);
```

or change the fetch_array function to this, and leave the rest as it is:

```
var index = 0;
function fetch_array(arr){
   return arr[index++]; 
}
```

You would have to reset the index variable to 0 if you wanted to loop through it again though.

Comment: i would like to be able to use the while( fn ) method so the secound suggestion is better, but i prefer a single fn and no global variable (if you use the same method twice)

Answer (score 0):

You have the array item available in your loop so you could always recreate it if you wanted. Or just copy it before you use your `fetch_array` function.

Alternatively just loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers joy want to support, array.forEach could be an option:

```
result.forEach(function(row) {
    alert("my name is " + row["name"] + " And I'm " + row['age'] + " years old");
});
```

Or if you use jQuery:

```
$(result).each(function() {
    var row = this;
    alert("my name is " + row["name"] + " And I'm " + row['age'] + " years old");
});
```

Comment: don't want to use any 3d party lib. 
And its not really a array i'm working with, this is just an example

Comment: In that case, you either want a for loop or to do something like @Fabrizio is doing below.  On that note, though, isn't `mysql_fetch_row` destructive, in that you can't seek backwards?  If so, your current implementation is an accurate conversion.